# Angular (8) mensagem em validação do formulário

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou trabalhando em um Input que precisa ter uma mensagem :

Digite pelo menos 10 caracteres

essa mensagem deve mudar a cada carácter que é digitado

Entao, ao digitar:

Alex

a mensagem deveria ser:

### Digite pelo menos mais 6 caracteres

o meu problema é como conseguir o tamanho da string:

```
<input
type="text"
formControlName="nome" 
class="form-control"
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && nome.invalid && (nome.dirty || nome.touched), 'is-valid': (nome.valid && nome.touched ) }">
```

.

```
<div class="text-muted" *ngIf="nome?.value.length < 10 ">
digite pelo menos mais {{10 - nome?.value.length }} caracteres </div>
```

Mas ao iniciar o "nome" esta undefined, e isso quebra a aplicação,

alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Um ajuste simples seria, criar um get pro seu form

```
get formControl() { return this.form.controls; }
```

no html:

```
formControl.nome.length < 10
```

mas o correto não seria fazer assim, o correto fazer é criar um validator, crie um arquivo ts ou uma função

```
function minCaracterValue(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
   if (control.value && (isNaN(control.value) || control.value < 10) {
      return { 'minCaracter': true };
   }
   return null;
}
```

ou pode ser um metodo na classe também. O form ficaria assim

```
  this.form= new FormGroup({
       nome: new FormControl(null, [minCaracterValue])
    });
```

no seu template html ficaria assim

```
<p *ngIf="formControl.nome.errors.minCaracter">digite pelo menos mais {{10 - formControl.nome.value }} caracteres</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro pode ser corrigido pelo duplo uso do Operador Elvis

nome?.value.length

não funciona porque o value também é nulo,

deveria ser:

nome.value?.length

ou

nome?.value?.length

Comment: E como adicionou a palavra "mais"? Quando há algo digitado, de acordo com a pergunta, a frase precisa ser "pelo menos **mais** X caracteres". E se for digitado 12 caracteres aparecerá "pelo menos mais -2 caracteres"?

Comment: Ajustei a pergunta, 
agora a palavra 'mais' existe desde de começo. 

grato pela correção.

Comment: Ué, ao invés de adaptar a solução você adapta o problema? haha xD

Comment: Usa o comando `(input)` na tag `input` para atualizar o valor. Ex:
`html5
<input
type="text"
formControlName="nome" 
class="form-control"
(input)="contaCaracteres()"
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && nome.invalid && (nome.dirty || nome.touched), 'is-valid': (nome.valid && nome.touched ) }">
`

Ai no componente, dentro da função contaCaracteres(), tu pode fazer `meuForm.get('nome').value.length` e armazenar em outra variável o valor que retorna. É uma maneira de tu sempre contar os caracteres de uma string no input.

Comment: Ou, como ta usando FormGroup, pode tentar usar o comando `meuForm.get('nome').value.length` na div que vai mostrar a mensagem